# Flash clock into javascript & css clock same images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, flash

### [*DEMO*](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/analog-flash-clock-generator)

but problem is that Flash needs to install adobe flash player in some browsers. That's why i want it in Html, Css, JavaScript & jQuery.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! One of the first things you will learn about asking questions, is a lot of the time, a simple search will yield the results you are looking for :) I googled "make an analog clock in js" and found multiple sites telling how to do it, on the first result page. http://randomibis.com/coolclock/ and http://www.kirupa.com/html5/create_an_analog_clock_using_the_canvas.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're going to need some CSS3 to rotate things, which will limit you in that IE8 and below won't work

have a look at https://css-tricks.com/examples/CSS3Clock/

Comment: i am unable to change it's size (using chrome developer tool). Have a look?